# Keep static site root in subdirectory (reverse proxy)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a small static subsite for example `www.example.com/foo/` and I use the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;

    proxy_pass http://example-site/;
  }

  location /foo {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;

    proxy_pass http://example-web-foo/;
  }
}
```

However, when I use some root-based URI in the site, for example `/assets/css/style.css`, it translates to `https://example.com/assets/css/style.css`, not `https://example.com/foo/assets/css/style.css`.

Is there any way to specify the root in the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify the root in the proxy by using the `proxy_set_header` directive to edit the `X-Forwarded-URI` header!

check this out:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-URI $request_uri; # Add this line
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;

    proxy_pass http://example-site/;
  }

  location /foo {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-URI $request_uri; # Add this line
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;

    proxy_pass http://example-web-foo/;
  }
}
```